# azure sql database のファイアーウォール設定について

Tags: azure

azure sql databaseのサーバーファイアーウォールの項目にazure サービスおよびリソースにこのサーバーへのアクセスを許可するというチェックボックスがありますがこれにチェックを入れると自分だけのazureサービスからだけ(azure app serviceなど) サーバのアクセスを許可するという理解であっているのでしょうか？

もし違うのであれば自分がazure内のazure app serviceに発行したアプリケーションだけからazure sql databaseにアクセスを許可するファイアーウォールの設定の仕方を教えていただきたいです。